# confused with .then() in promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, resolve

I'm new to js and I'm learning promises. I came up with this code which will print the resolved values from every function and will call new functions using `.then`

```
function login() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {

            resolve({username : 'default'})
        }, 1000)
    })
}

function getVideos() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(['vid1', 'vid2'])
        },1000)
    })
}

function getDesc() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {

            resolve('desc')
        }, 1000)
    })
}


const test = login()
test.then(res => {
    console.log(res)
    getVideos()
})
.then(res => {
    console.log(res)
    getDesc()
})
.then(res => console.log(res))
```

But, I'm not getting the expected result, I thought all the statements in `.then()` needed to be executed and resolved to continue to the next `.then()` statement. But clearly this is not the case here as I'm getting the following as the output -

```
{ username: 'default' }
undefined
undefined
```

But I expected the output to be similar to this -

```
{username : 'default}
['vid1', 'vid2']
desc
```

pls, point where I'm going wrong here. Any help is appreciated, thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `return` to inside your chains when you're calling those functions. For example:

```
function login() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {

            resolve({username : 'default'})
        }, 1000)
    })
}

function getVideos() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(['vid1', 'vid2'])
        },1000)
    })
}

function getDesc() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {

            resolve('desc')
        }, 1000)
    })
}


const test = login()
test.then(res => {
    console.log(res)
    return getVideos()
})
.then(res => {
    console.log(res)
    return getDesc()
})
.then(res => console.log(res))
```

This is a good guide: https://javascript.info/promise-chaining

Comment: Yup this is the solution. Might help to mention that OP was seeing `undefined` *because* of the missing return statements—a function without a return statement will return `undefined`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#:~:text=The%20then()%20method%20returns,failure%20cases%20of%20the%20Promise%20.

Comment: @dwosk thanks, can you also link any good guides for async and await, the one in mdn did not suffice

Answer (score 1):

Make a couple of very minor changes:

```
const test = login()
test.then(res => {
  console.log(res)
  return getVideos()
})
.then(res => {
  console.log(res)
  return getDesc()
})
.then(res => console.log(res))
```

To chain promises together, you need to return the promises at each step. As it is you're implicitly returning `undefined` which is not a promise.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it now.